# std::fs::File::create().unwrap() throws the error when file or directory doesn't exist in rust

Tags: rust

```
pub fn create_batched_writer(schema: &polars::prelude::Schema) -> BatchedWriter<File> {
    let mut file = std::fs::File::create("output/test.parquet").unwrap();
    let writer = ParquetWriter::new(file);
    writer.batched(schema).unwrap()
}
```

when the file or the directory doesn't exist, it will panic as showed below.

```
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }
```

My question is how would I create the the file and directory when it is found not existed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming that this error occurred because the directory *"output"* didn't exist, based on that, you can try the following code:

```rust
pub fn create_batched_writer(schema: &Schema) -> BatchedWriter<File> {
    let file_path = "output/test.parquet";
    
    // Checking if the directory exists and creating if not
    let parent_dir = Path::new(file_path).parent().unwrap();
    if !parent_dir.exists() {
        fs::create_dir_all(parent_dir).expect("Failed to create directory");
    }

    let file = File::create(file_path);
    let writer = ParquetWriter::new(file);
    writer.batched(schema).unwrap()
}
```

Comment: Although note that in "hostile" contexts, this suffers from TOCTOU issues, both in the first step (dir can have been created from under you between the exists and create_dir_all checks), and second step (directory can be removed between the block and the create). Sadly the stdlib only has path-based FS functions as far as I know (no fd / handle-based `at` variants).

Comment: Also `Path::is_dir` might be a good idea for similar reasons (or calling into `metadata` which should be more reliable), for similar reason: the path could exist but be a path to a directory, in which case file creation will still fail.

Comment: @Masklinn I think I'd just create things without checking existence, first by assuming the directory exists, then try creating the directory if that fails.  Tends to be easier than checking all the failure modes, which the kernel will also be checking against when it does the create.

Comment: *I used the return keyword instead of just writing the line without a semi-colon(;), but you can surely stick to your way, I like my code to be easily readable* - please note that "the OP's way" is considered idiomatic in Rust, and is used in 99.9% of Rust code you will encounter. There is nothing "unreadable" about it. I'm aware it's ultimately a matter of taste and opinion, but StackOverflow answers should strive to be authoritative, and yours falls short with that last sentence.

Comment: @user4815162342
I totally agree with you, and yes I shouldn't be giving opinion-based statements here, but the reason behind my statement was that I believe a lot of rust learners are familiar with the conventional return keyword, it's just easier for us than adapting to this new syntax, and although this new syntax is encouraged, there is nothing wrong with sticking to the old one.

Comment: @YashJ But there *is* something wrong. "Learners" are called that for a reason - the idea is to learn. In this case you are going out of your way to modify the OP's perfectly fine and idiomatic Rust into a less usual form that would fail a code review and probably get flagged by clippy to boot. That's not helping.